# React set message while contacting service

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that I want to display a message to tell the user that it is communicating to a service and once complete remove the message. I can't seem to get it to work. When I click on the button all the children then display, "loading..." and the message will never go away

```
class RecipeList extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { Names: [], loadingMessage: "" };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const settings = appConfig;
        fetch(settings.RestServerLocation + "/Api/recipe", {
            headers : { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
               }    
        })
            .then(result => {
                return result.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ Names: data })
            });
    }

    render() {
        const recipeListItems = this.state.Names.map((recipeName) =>

            <li key={recipeName.Name.toString()}className="row" item={recipeName.Name}>
                <Col xs="12" md="6">{recipeName.Name}</Col>
                <Col xs="12" md="6">{this.state.loadingMessage}
                    <Button size="sm" onClick={() => this.props.viewclick(this, recipeName.Id)}>View recipe</Button>
                </Col>
            </li>
        );
        return (
            <div>
                <Card className="card-modified">
                    <CardHeader>Recipe List</CardHeader>
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardText>
                            <ul>
                                {recipeListItems}
                            </ul>
                        </CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

And it's parent has code

```
recipeListViewClickHandler = (w, id) => {
    const settings = appConfig;
    w.state.loadingMessage = "loading..."
    fetch(settings.RestServerLocation + "/Api/recipe/" + id)
      .then(result => {
        return result.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        //const foo = data;
        this.setState({ Recipe: data })
        w.state.loadingMessage = "complete";
      }
      )
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
        return e;
      });
  }
```

Along with this code in the render

```
<Col xs="12" lg="8"><RecipeList addclick={this.recipeListAddClickHandler} viewclick={this.recipeListViewClickHandler} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an anti-pattern for you to be setting the state of a child component in the parent, but by calling `w.state.loadingMessage`, you aren't telling the component to update, so it will never know to change.  The `setState()` function will set the `state` property while telling the component to update.  You *might* be able to get away with `w.setState({loadingMessage: "complete"})` but you really shouldn't do that.

If you want to set the loading message from the parent, set the state *in* the parent (`this.setState({loadingMessage: "complete"})`) instead of on the child, and then pass it in to the child as a property instead.

```
render() {
  const {loadingMessage} = this.state;

  return <Col xs="12" lg="8">
    <RecipeList
      addclick={this.recipeListAddClickHandler}
      viewclick={this.recipeListViewClickHandler}
      loadingMessage={loadingMessage}
    />
  </Col>;
}
```

**Edit**
Based on your comments, I've realized that the way you are going about it is a bit backwards.  In the list component, you are getting the collection from the API, but or the instance data, you are fetching from the parent.  You are missing a child component here.  `ListItem` should be extracted as a component, and can manage the state for itself :)

```
class RecipeListItem extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.setState({loadingMessage: ""});
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const {recipeName} = this.props;
    const settings = appConfig;

    this.setState({loadingMessage: "loading..."});
    fetch(`${settings.RestServerLocation}/Api/recipe/${recipeName.id}`)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({loadingMessage: "complete"});
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({loadingMessage: "ERROR"});
        return e;
      });
  }

  render() {
    const {recipeName} = this.props;

    return <li
      key={recipeName.Name.toString()}
      className="row"
      item={recipeName.Name}
    >
      <Col xs="12" md="6">{recipeName.Name}</Col>
      <Col xs="12" md="6">
        {this.state.loadingMessage}
        <Button size="sm" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          View recipe
        </Button>
      </Col>
    </li>;
  }
}
```

Then, in your List component, just use the child:

```
render() {
    const recipeListItems = this.state.Names.map((recipeName) =>
        <RecipeListItem recipeName={recipeName} />
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <Card className="card-modified">
                <CardHeader>Recipe List</CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                    <CardText>
                        <ul>
                            {recipeListItems}
                        </ul>
                    </CardText>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I actually have a list of items that each contain a button that queries a service. If I do as you suggest via setstate then it updates the values for all items. I just want it to update the text for a single item. Actually I say text but in the end I want it to be a spinning image or something.. Maybe it would simplify my code if I brought the server query inside that component. I'm still getting the hang of react and don't always know where to put the service calls etc..

Comment: Yeah, honestly, I'm not sure why the list component is getting the list from the API, but the parent gets the instance data from the API via the parent.  That is a bit backwards.  I've updated my answer to give a better example of what I mean.  

Honestly, though, having all that `fetch()` logic built into your component is a violation of SOC.  *IF* you care about that, you can move your data fetching into a state management system like Redux of MobX... but that is a different post ;)  Cheers.

Comment: P.S. It wouldn't be the end of the world to keep all the `loadingMessages` in the parent and push them down.  React is *really* good at this sort of thing... if the result of the render function doesn't yield a change in the DOM, it doesn't change the DOM.  And, if you change to derive from `PureComponent` instead of `Component` or implement `shouldComponentUpdate()`, you could avoid the re-render functions as well.  (Lots to learn, I know.  It all comes with time)

Comment: Thanks. I was going to attempt this exact thing today. This has been more on my own time so it's a little tough to get all the time to read and code. Basically get a list in the parent and send it to children via props, but let the children do updating and manage their own messaging. I was trying to limit service access to only certain components not a great idea. Do you have any resources that covers all these types of things I should learn?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `state` of your child component from a function inside your parent component. In React, the `state` of a component should never be mutated but should only be set using the `this.setState` method. So, you can change your code to

```
w.setState({loadingMessage:'complete'});
....
w.setState({loadingMessage:'loading...'});
```

and check if it works.

But I would suggest, that you refactor your code, so that

1. the child's `state` is modified only inside the child component
2. the `state` of the parent flows through to the child component as `props` along with any necessary actions (functions).
3. these actions allow the child to send any necessary data back to the parent

Without looking at more of your code, such refactoring would not be possible.